# Is there a more efficient compression algorithm than gzip?

Tags: memory, compression

I'd like to compress my files as much as possible. For this I've been compressing all my files to .tgz format, which yeilds really promising results. However is there something even better than this?

Answer (score 1):

Gzip is a program, not algorithm. Algorithm is Deflate (based on LZ77).

You may want to look at LZMA algorithm (or, if you're seeking software to use, xz).

Answer (score 0):

You can try PPM for text. Lzma is also good. For example Freearc its a very good and fast and free frontend and backend compressor.